# How to parse of jira-versions from Atlassian website

Tags: groovy, jira, jenkins-groovy

I am facing a problem. 
I have to parse JSON contained [list](https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/jira-core.json) of jira-core versions from Atlassian website.

While attempting to parse JSON from the website using a JsonSlurper, I get an error saying:

> "The current character read is 'd' with an int value of 100 Unable to
>   determine the current character, it is not a string, number,  array,
>   or object line number 1 index number 0"

Code:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/')
def html = http.get( path : 'current/jira-core.json')
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper(type: JsonParserType.LAX).parse(html)
print slurper
```

How do I need to get the correct JSON block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that's not json... It's a jsonp callback, so the valid json is wrapped in a `downloads( ... )` javascript call

You can use a regular expression to unwrap the text from the URL with:

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonp = new URL('https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/current/jira-core.json').text
def extract = jsonp =~ /^downloads\((.+)\)$/
if (!extract.matches()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Bad jsonp!")
}
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(extract.group(1))

parsed.each { println it.description }
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly address the JSON vs JSONP issue, if you are just looking to consume Jira version data, there is also a third-party site called [iapetus.fyi](https://iapetus.fyi) that provides Atlassian product version information, including the possibility of providing [Firebase notifications](https://iapetus.fyi/notifications) to your app for version change events.